# Transforming a second order ode into a Kummer's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to transform the equation

$y^2w''(y)−y(a+by)w'(y)+(c+dy+ey^2)w(y)=0$

into the form of a Kummer's or confluent hypergeometric differential equation:

$yw''(y)+(f−y)w'(y)-gw(y)=0$

I know it is possible to do so by using a transformation related to exponential functions, but I cannot come up with the right one even with many tries.

Thank you in advance for any help!